# capturing the error when using sys.exit()

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

Is it possible to capture the errors generated and return them to the caller script?

```
p1.py
def fun1():
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as err:
        print('ERROR from p1.py')
        sys.exit(1)



p2.py
import p1
def fun2():
    try:
        ...
     except Exception as err:
        print('ERROR from p2.py')
        sys.exit(1)
           
p3.py
import p2
#want to catch the errors here
errors1 = 'ERROR from p1.py'
errors2 = 'ERROR from p2.py'
```

Is there a way to get the errors from either p1.py ('ERROR from p1.py') or p2.py ('ERROR from p2.py') in p3.py?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be chaging where you handle the exception when you execute the functions of the p1.py and p2.py file in the p3.py file, you can do a try-except in p3.py(*instead of catching the exception inside of every function*):

**p3.py**

```
from p1 import fun1
from p2 import fun2

# calling the function from p1.py
try:
  fun1()
except Exception as err:
  print('You have the error from fun1 in p1.py, you can make your logic here')
  sys.exit(1)
# calling function from p2.py
try:
  fun2()
except Exception as err:
  print('You have the error from fun2 in p2.py, you can make your logic here')
  sys.exit(1)
```